# NodeJS Mysql2. Достать переменную из аргумента функции

Tags: node.js, функции

Всем привет! В nodeJS есть модуль mysql2 и результат запроса можно увидеть при помощи функции зашитой в аргумент запроса `base.execute("SQL", [], (err, results, fields) => {})` как можно достать переменную results?

Comment: В смысле? Вот же она. Передавайте в execute функцию и внутри этой функции смотрите на result сколько угодно.

Comment: Нужно чтобы эта переменная была доступна за пределами функции

Comment: Тогда дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554290/190728

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)